# SQL code is complying but the three columns after first only show NULL

Tags: sql

```
USE AdventureWorks2014

SELECT 
    prom.name, 
    SUM(sod.LineTotal) AS ProductSalesTotal, 
    SUM(sod.UnitPrice) AS ProductSalesNoDiscount, 
    SUM(sod.UnitPriceDiscount) AS ProductLosstoDiscount
FROM  
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
FULL JOIN 
    Production.Product AS prom ON prom.ProductModelID = sod.ProductID
GROUP BY 
    prom.Name;
```

This is the code I have so far, not sure why the 3 columns after the first just say NULL

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I would be really surprised if sales orders had invalid products.  At least, they wouldn't in any reasonable data model.

So, if you want all products, use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT prom.name, 
       SUM(sod.LineTotal) AS ProductSalesTotal, 
       SUM(sod.UnitPrice) AS ProductSalesNoDiscount, 
       SUM(sod.UnitPriceDiscount) AS ProductLosstoDiscount
FROM Production.Product AS prom LEFT JOIN
     Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
     ON prom.ProductModelID = sod.ProductID
GROUP BY prom.Name;
```

The `SUM()`s would be `NULL` if there were no match.  That seems suspicious but the place to look is the `JOIN` clause.  Perhaps `ProductModelId` doesn't match to `ProductId`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do any operations on NULL column, it will make your entire answer NULL.

So if you sum, add, subtract, or even try to concatenate a string and any of the values are NULL the result will be NULL regardless the rest of the data.

This should fix it.  It checks if the column value is NULL, then makes it 0 before it tries to SUM.

```
USE AdventureWorks2014

SELECT prom.name, sum(ISNULL(sod.LineTotal, 0)) as ProductSalesTotal, sum(ISNULL(sod.UnitPrice, 0)) as ProductSalesNoDiscount, sum(ISNULL(sod.UnitPriceDiscount, 0) as ProductLosstoDiscount

FROM  Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod

FULL JOIN Production.Product as prom ON prom.ProductModelID = sod.ProductID

Group by prom.Name;
```

Comment: IIRC, this is not true of SUM and some other numeric aggregates, as long as there is at least one non-null value.

Comment: That worked however its now only showing zeros

Comment: Is there actual data in your columns?  If you select just the data without using SUM, does anything come back?

Comment: There should be data returned, i believe for some reason the joins are messed up and caused every value to be null

Comment: Well that sounds like the issue then, once you get the join fixed and data showing up, the query should work.